# How to get a list of tables which contains a common column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a number of tables in which some of them has common `Asset_ID`, what will be the query to get a list of table names with common `Asset_ID`.

Comment: Which sql server version?

Comment: Please be more specific when asking question. It is always advised to provide some sample of what you are expecting.

Comment: it is on sql server 2008. in a single database i have 10 tables, in each table there is column "asset_id", now, let us say there are 4 tables where asset_it='ddn224', how do i generate a list of table where asset_id ='ddn224'.

Answer (score 2):

try `select table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name='Asset_ID'`

If you want to get the table names depending on the value of data in the column you cannot get it by simple query try the following

```
declare @val_to_search varchar(50), @column_name varchar(50)
Select @val_to_search = 'ddh224', @column_name='Asset_ID'

declare tbl cursor for 
select table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name=@column_name
declare @tablename varchar(200),@qstr varchar(max)
declare @datapen table(table_name varchar(200))

open tbl
fetch tbl into @tablename
while @@fetch_status=0
begin
select @qstr='select top 1 '''+@tablename+''' from '+@tablename+' where '+ @column_name + ' =''' + @val_to_search + ''''
insert into @datapen
exec(@qstr)

fetch tbl into @tablename
end
close tbl
deallocate tbl
select * from @datapen pen
```

Comment: i want to select only the names of those tables which has same values of asset_id.like where asset_id="ddh224". so it only select the table name where asset_id="ddh224"

Comment: it gives a syntax error in the select @qsrt line in server2008

Comment: What is the error message? I tested this in 2005, 2008 R2 and 2012

Comment: @kingshuk I tried it again in sql server 2008 R2 and it is running perfectly. can you post the exact code you were running?

Comment: i am sending the exact code which i am trying to run. my e-mail-id, is "kingshuk.india@gmail.com" it is getting bigger by some no. can i have ur email id please...

Comment: Make changes to the second line only. You don't need to change anything other than that. Please don't add extra spaces

Answer (score 0):

Below Query might help u out!

This query will list down all tables along with Columns Names!

> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME LIKE
>   '%columnName%'

This query will list down all tables!

> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE
>   TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tableName%'

Answer (score 0):

i always use this to find all match keyword, it will list down all match sp, tables, function...

```
select distinct name 
from syscomments c 
join sysobjects o on c.id = o.id 
where TEXT like '%Asset_ID%'
```